# Photoshop: How to duplicate layer manual without using hotkey

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I read many tutorials and found that, hotkey to duplicate layer is `Command + J` on Mac or `Control + J` on Windows.

My question is: If I don't remember this hotkey, how can I do this manual. (By clicking icon or go to menu and submenu ...)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the menu `Layer > Duplicate Layer...`

Or drag a layer in the **Layers Panel** to the *New Layer* icon at the bottom of the panel.